# PHP file format upload

Tags: php, file-upload

So this is a snip of my current PHP script:

```
// Check if the form was submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // Check if file was uploaded without errors
    if(isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == 0){
        //$allowed = array("PNG" => "image/png");
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
        $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];
    
        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Choose between .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png. Your format is: $ext");
```

So currently these extensions are allowed: `.jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png`. When someone add image with extension `image.jpg` it works fine, but when trying to save `image.JPG, it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtolower()` to make what is sent to you, into lower case like the data you are comparing to.

```
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_change_key_case()` to convert all cases to lower, and check on the lowercase key in `array_key_exists()`. `array_change_key_case()` changes all keys to lowercase by default (but you can also change them to uppercase, by supplying the `CASE_UPPER` to the second argument - `CASE_LOWER` is default).

This of course means that the key you're looking for, must be lowercase when you're passing it to the first argument of `array_key_exists()`. You pass a variable through, you can use `strtolower()` to ensure that it is.

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!array_key_exists(strtolower($ext), $allowed)) die("Error: Choose between .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png. Your format is: $ext");
```